# Tidyverse R: how to change a tuple-table into straight tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to do the following, changing tupple-style rows (without header) of data into a table with headers, with Tidyverse. The new command gather apparently can handle this.

**How can I gather the wide table into a straight table or with some other modern Tidyverse tools?**

```
library(tidyverse)
INLINE_LOAD ="Car,Merse,Speed,10,Other,ot
Car,Ferra,Speed,20,Other,ot2
Car,Volve,Speed,30,Other,ot3
Car,Miiss,Speed,40,Other,ot4"
```

*Wanted Output*

```
Car,Speed,Other
Merse,10,ot
Ferra,20,ot2
Volve,30,ot3
Miiss,40,ot4
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Do u have the column names or is it the first line that is the column name

Comment: @akrun there is no column names as a header. Column names are on each row: each odd value is a column name. Column names are `Car`, `Speed` and `Other`.

Comment: Downvoter please comment for the reason.

Comment: Not the downvoter but here are a couple of reasons: No reproducible example, No attempt to solve YOUR problem. People tend to get frustrated when all you post is *I have this and I want this*

Answer (score 1):

With the tidyverse:

```
df %>% select(Car = 2, Speed = 4, Other = 6)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     Car Speed  Other
  <fctr> <int> <fctr>
1  Merse    10     ot
2  Ferra    20    ot2
3  Volve    30    ot3
4  Miiss    40    ot4
```

With base R:

```
dfnew <- df[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]
names(dfnew) <- unlist(unique(df[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]))
```

The result:

```
> dfnew
    Car Speed Other
1 Merse    10    ot
2 Ferra    20   ot2
3 Volve    30   ot3
4 Miiss    40   ot4
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse);df <- read_delim("Input.csv", ",");dfnew <- df[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]` firing the error `Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 6 (the number of rows), not 2`

Comment: @hhh that is because tidyverse messes with the dataframe format; I added a tidyverse solution to my answer as well; for the base R you can do `dfnew <- as.data.frame(df)[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]`

Comment: @hhh added another soltuion at the end, I hope that helps

Comment: yes that is the most elegant so far +1, perhaps you could simplify the answer -- it is a bit hard reading and I can only get the last one working with the InlineLoad `INLINE_LOAD ="Car,Merse,Speed,10,Other,ot
Car,Ferra,Speed,20,Other,ot2
Car,Volve,Speed,30,Other,ot3
Car,Miiss,Speed,40,Other,ot4";

df <- read_delim(INLINE_LOAD, ",", col_names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

We first use inline load and then apply the following transformations

```
library(tidyverse)
INLINE_LOAD ="Car,Merse,Speed,10,Other,ot
Car,Ferra,Speed,20,Other,ot2
Car,Volve,Speed,30,Other,ot3
Car,Miiss,Speed,40,Other,ot4"

read_delim(INLINE_LOAD, ",", col_names=FALSE) %>% 
    select(c(2,4,6)) %>% 
    select(Car=X2,Speed=X4,Other=X6)
```

where renaming of the columns and selecting only the odd columns. There is a more elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46587584/164148) with only one select.

This is not a very elegant solution when a large number of columns.